# Expected Int, got IntProgression instead

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get on Kotlin so I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhA-Q7MOre0) of their own.

So they're trying to create a sequence given a string, such as this:

```
"a vect" -> [
     a vect  :
     a vec   :   t
     a ve    :   ct
     ...
]
```

And the way to do it is, according to the video, the following:

```
val seq = sequenceOf(canonicalisedInput.lastIndex + 1 downTo 0).map {
    canonicalisedInput.substring(0, it) to canonicalisedInput.substring(it)
}
```

And I get what I does (well, the idea of it). The problem is that `substring` expects two `Int`s, while `it` (which I assume is an implicit iterator of some sorts that comes from the `downTo` progression) is an `IntProgression`. Same for the second `substring` call.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted contains a mistake: [`sequenceOf(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence-of.html) with single argument passed returns a sequence with that one item, that is, `Sequence<IntProgression>` . To get a sequence of indices (`Sequence<Int>`), use [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) function instead:

```
 (canonicalisedInput.lastIndex + 1 downTo 0).asSequence().map { ... }
```

---

The `substring(...)` function called second is [the overload that returns the substring starting from the index passed as the argument](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html).

And `it` is the [implicit name for the innermost lambda single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax), in your case it is the parameter of `map`, that is, the sequence item to be mapped by the lambda.

So, the expression inside lambda is a pair (created by [`to` infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html)) of two substring, one from the beginning of the original string to the index in the sequence, the other one -- from that index to the end of the string.

So the code should definitely work with indices sequence, that's why the mistake is quite clear.

Comment: I fail to see why in my case it reports an error while in the official tutorial it's alright. How do I pass an index to the substring method then?

Comment: @dabadaba, now I see, the code you posted contains a mistake. `sequenceOf` with single argument passed returns a sequence with that one item. To get a sequence of indices, try `(canonicalisedInput.lastIndex + 1 downTo 0).asSequence()` instead.

Comment: @dabadaba that tutorial was filmed before the release of Kotlin. `sequenceOf(IntProgression)` function was deprecated and removed before release.

Answer (score 3):

`sequenceOf(canonicalisedInput.lastIndex + 1 downTo 0)` —
this expression creates a sequence which consists of a single `IntProgression` item.

If you want to convert an `IntProgression` to a `Sequence<Int>`, use `asSequence` extension function:

```
(canonicalisedInput.length downTo 0).asSequence()
```